# Custom static BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, static, broadcastreceiver, message

I staticly define the broadcastreceiver with a custom action named "com.lpj.test". As is registered in the AndroidManifest.xml below:

```
<receiver android:name=".TestBroadcast">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.lpj.test"/>
            </intent-filter>
```

The coustome BroadcastReceiver Class is like this:

```
public class TestBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
public static final String RECEIVER = "com.lpj.test";
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVER)){
        Log.i("BroadcastTest", "Broadcast Start!");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast Start!",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

}

Then sending an intent to my BroadcastReceiver in the main activity

```
public class replyer extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_replyer);
    this.findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.lpj.test"));
        }
    });
}
```

}

It didn't work at all when I clicked the button.Neither did the Logcat present a message with TAG "BroadcastTest",nor did the Toast-Box popup.Nothing happened.

Comment: In name instead of giving .TestBroadcast use it with package name for eg. com.mypackage.TestBroadcast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is **.** (dot) in the action name, Try following way,

```
<receiver android:name=".TestBroadcast">
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="comLpjTest"/>
</intent-filter>


@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    sendBroadcast(new Intent("comLpjTest"));
}
```

Comment: Not working with me